# C# MySQL SELECT with null

Tags: c#, mysql, select, null, zero

i have numbers in table. For example 0050. In database is 0050 exactly, because i set ZEROFILL.
But now when i want SELECT this number in C#, it shows only 50 without 2 nulls.

My code:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string input = label1.Text.Trim();
       string conn = "server=46.28.110.147;user=asqasdqdq;password=qdqdqd;database=qdqdqwdqd;";
       MySqlConnection myconn = new MySqlConnection(conn);
       string sql = "SELECT numbers FROM vfr WHERE used=0 ORDER BY numbers LIMIT 1";
       MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, myconn);
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       da.Fill(dt);

       label1.Text = dt.Rows[0][0] + "";


   }
```

Thank you

Comment: you seem to be confused: string "0050" is not the same as 50

Comment: is numbers, (which by the way is a very bad name for a column that holds one number) an int type. ZeroFill is useless unless it's a string type,any leading zeros will get dropped because ints don't have them 0050 = 50.

Comment: But i have problem only with SELECT. So i edited first post. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because no matter what ZEROFILL means a number, stored as a number contains no formatting information.  If you are storing the number as a string, then maybe, but if you then convert it to a number when you bring it in to C# you would still have the exact same issue.  Numbers contain no formatting information in C# either.  To control formatting is a separate process.  check out [.NetFormatStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

```
 var x = 0050;
 Console.Write(x);
 Console.Write(x.ToString("0000"));
```

Comment: Thank you, but i can´t use it, because in database are more numbers.

Comment: By the way, problem is only in SELECT, UPDATE is for another operation. :)
I edited first post

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where numbers is null

select * from table where numbers is not null
```

or

```
update table set numbers =1 where numbers is null

update table set numbers =1 where numbers is not null
```

Comment: Thank you, but i cant use it because i have another SELECT command:
SELECT numbers FROM vfr WHERE used=0 ORDER BY numbers LIMIT 1

Comment: The OP seems to be using "null" to mean "zero", rather than a SQL `null`. If the question *were* about `null`, I'd suggest more explanation about the `is null` and `is not null` tests.

Comment: select isnull(numbers, 0), isnull(null,123)

Comment: maybe it correct

select isnull(null, null, null, numbers, 1 )